# Xerox WorkCentre 5335 - Out of Paper Error

Tags: drivers, printing, xerox

Trying to print from a Xerox WorkCentre 5335 because the office insisted it was Ubuntu compatible (nobody else has figured it out yet, either. The higher-ups use Windows, so they don't care). I've tried using the provided installation .sh file for the driver provided by Xerox, and it just closes after I hit "I Agree". So, I tried using the Windows generic PPD supplied by Xerox. It adds to my system accordingly after supplying the PPD to CUPS, but when I try to print (from any tray) it just says "Out of Paper". Any ideas?

Comment: You have to execute the .sh file as root. Did you use sudo? If not, you should use sudo. Source: http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/drivers/WC58XA/userdocs/any-os/en/en.Xerox_UNIX_Printer_Driver_Readme.pdf

Comment: open a terminal, type `sudo` then press space and drag and drop the install.sh file into the terminal and press enter

Comment: Of course I used `sudo`. It still doesn't run after I click "I agree"...

Comment: I see what's happening, it's trying to install a .RPM file. I tried snagging a screenshot, but it went away before I could.

Comment: you can convert an RPM file to DEB format if that's all that's available and then just double-click it.  (Fair warning: I've done that before, but never for a printer driver!)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. It says "installing RPM file" in a window that flashes, then closes. All I had available for download was a .sh file. I will try to open it up and view what's actually in the .sh when I get a chance. Last few times I tried, gedit just became unresponsive and force quit.

Comment: you can use alien to convert an rpm to deb, although it usually results in "broken pipe" message and won't install but it's certainly worth a try. If you can, try to locate a .deb file instead or as a last resort, extract the rpm and manually copy and paste the files to the correct directories yourself.

Comment: Was able to convert and install, but all it install were some files called "xeroxdriver", "xeroxprntmanager", and "XeroxQscript" in the opt/Xerox/prntsys folder, nothing usable by CUPS as far as I could find. I'm just going to buy another little printer for us on the lower levels to use.